# How to change the title; the xlabel; the ylabel; the legend and labels of a plot returned by the abc_analysis package on Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, package

To display Pareto's law I use the abc_analysis package (python version and not R), it returns the results with plot using the matplotlib package.

In the instructions for use, no arguments are given to modify the title; xlabels; ylabels along with all other labels and the legend.

Is it possible to circumvent this?

Here is the data and the code I used:

```py
from abc_analysis import abc_analysis, abc_plot

df = pd.DataFrame({"Sales":[175.25, 97, 30, 11, 7, 5, 3]})
df.index = ["Prod_1", "Prod_2", "Prod_3", "Prod_4", "Prod_5", "Prod_6", "Prod_7"]

abc = abc_analysis(df["Sales"], True)
```

Here is the result obtained:

[image: abc plot]

**Edit 1:** the package `abc_analysis` don't use plt.show()

The `abc_analysis` package automatically generates the curve representing Paretto's law with ABC analysis.

The plot automatically generated by `abc_analysis` uses the `matplotlib` package.

Two commands to generate it:

```py
abc_analysis(psData, boolPlotResult=True)
```

Or

```py
abc_plot(dctResult)
```

It then generates the plot without having to write a single line of code using `matplotlib` package in its source code.

I had already tried the command to no avail:

```py
abc_plot(abc).set_title("New title")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(my_pandas) 07:44 boffi@localhost:~/Documents/my_pandas $ python
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 19 2022, 21:56:32) [GCC] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from abc_analysis import *
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Sales":[175.25, 97, 30, 11, 7, 5, 3]})
>>> df.index = ["Prod_1", "Prod_2", "Prod_3", "Prod_4", "Prod_5", "Prod_6", "Prod_7"]
>>> abc = abc_analysis(df["Sales"], 0)
>>> ax = abc_plot(abc)
>>> ax.set_title("At Last")
Text(0.5, 1.0, 'At Last')
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Please do as follows

1. Please find where `abc_analysis.py` is installed (for me it's `./lib/python3.9/site-packages/abc_analysis/abc_analysis.py`) and modify the `abc_plot` function , changing the last lines of the function to look like this

   ```
        # show complete plot
        # plt.show() # NO NO NO NO NO NO NO NO
        return ax
   ```
2. in your code, at the beginning,

   ```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ```
3. do not use the option to plot from the `abc_analysis` function and call explicitly the `abc_plot` function, like this — note that now `abc_plot` returns an Axes object that you can modify at your will

   ```
   abc = abc_analysis(df["Sales"], False)
   ax = abc_plot(abc)
   ```
4. modify the properties of the Axes object, e.g., `ax.set_title('At Last")`
5. when everything is fine, call `plt.show()` from your code

I have to say the the organization of the module is not optimal.

Comment: I reproduced my code in an example, I didn't add anything more and/or less, your answer would make perfect sense if I had generated the plot myself by typing some code using the ```matplolib``` library.
As specified in my question, the plot is returned by ```abc_analysis``` and not by a ```plt.show()``` which I grant you would have been simple.
So your answer can't work, and I even tried it in good faith but it reproduces a new all-white plot below the one generated by abc_analysis.
If it works, I apologize for not understanding its subtlety. Thank you for the time you spent on my problem.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't see your answer, this is perfect thank you so much @gboffi.